# Input checkbox with multiple value on laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox, implode

I'm making input using the checkbox, only hardware table need to input multiple checkbox values
When im trying using implode, i got appear errorException: "implode(): Invalid arguments passed".

Here my controller code :

```
auth()->user()->Form()->create
([
    'user_id' => $request->user_id,
    'os' => $request->os,

    'hardware' => implode(',', $request->input('hardware')),
    // $arrayToString = implode(',', $request->input('hardware'));

    'software' => $request->software,
    'signature' => $signature,
    'status_desc' => $request->status_desc,
    'cancel_deskripsi' => $request->cancel_deskripsi
]);


dd($form);
return redirect()->route('form')->with('status', 'success');
```

My view code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label>Hardware :</label>
<div class="checkbox-list">
    <label class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hardware" name="hardware[]" value="Komputer AIO">
        <span></span>
        Komputer AIO
    </label>
    <label class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-group" id="hardware" name="hardware" value="Laptop">
        <span></span>
        Laptop
    </label>
    <input id="other" name="how" type="checkbox" class="form-group">
    <label for="other" class="form-group">Other :</label>
    <div class="other-disclosure">
        <input type="text" name="hardware" id="os-other" class="form-group col-md-2" placeholder="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have all those inputs named `hardware[]` (so they will all end up in an array as the input `hardware`) and incase nothing is passed (unchecked checkboxes) you should make sure to handle this:

```
'hardware' => implode(',', (array) $request->input('hardware', []));
```

Here if nothing is passed then `$request->input('hardware', [])` is `[]`, an array. The `(array)` cast is just to make sure there is an array being passed to `implode`.